# Hiding the UINavigation Controller button

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Is there a way to hide the navigation controller button from the navigation bar in Storyboards?

I don t want the user to be able to go back to the previous view using the navigation controller

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite simply using this code in your `(void)viewDidLoad` method:

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

**Edit**: if you have further navigation in the view (i.e if the view can navigate forward to other views which are allowed to go back to it) it might be a good idea to implement it in the `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

or

```
  self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: I do not mean the button as a "Bar button item" , I mean the navigation button , similar to the one on the left in this image:
http://www.doctohelp.com/newimages/Products/ScreenShots/StudioiPhone/iphone_navigationlist_rounded_types_landscape.png